# Существуют ли модификаторы CSS кроме !important?

Tags: css, css3

На [этой странице документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyPriority) сказано:

> метод `style.getPropertyPriority(property)` возвращает приоритет, например *"important"*

Почему там указано ***"e.g.|например"***?

Разве есть другие модификаторы свойств приоритета?

Comment: судя по [спецификации](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertypriority) может возвращать только `important` и пустую строку

Comment: Поддержка возможности вернуть какие-то иные DOMString-значения введена для возможности, если таковое будет требоваться в будущем, реализации прочих приоритетов. На текущий момент такая необходимость не рассматривается.

Comment: @7-zete-7 это единственное что пришло мне в голову. Просто удивительно - как долго живет этот метод и ничего не прибавилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае, метод используется лишь для того, чтобы узнать есть ли свойство "important".

Других модификаторов приоритета нет. Остальные повышения приоритета (специфичность) достигается за счет селекторов и их сочетаний. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Единственным разумным объяснением является - _возможность расширить этот функционал другими именами_, даже для установки требуется явно указать имя этого модификатора. Иначе этот метод должен был бы возвращать булевое значение.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, скорее всего раньше заложили возможность расширения, но потом изменилась концепция всей технологии и этот метод остался просто доживать свой век.  За 7 лет работы с фронтом ни разу не встречал этот метод в работе.